# Eclipse generates same xmi:id for different elements

Tags: eclipse, persistence, e4, eclipse-emf

After I close my application eclipse generates same xmi:id in workbench.xmi for two different menu items. Commands associated with these menu items also have the same xmi:id (but different from menu ids). Because of this two different menu items launch the same command.

These items and commands are specified in two different fragments and they already have the same ids in fragment.e4xmi. I think eclipse doesn't keep them unique if they are in different fragments.

What factors affect the resulting ids and how can I make eclipse generate different ids?

Comment: Why do you care about these ids? They are not something you normally use.

Comment: @greg-449 I forgot to mention, that commands associated with these menu items also have the same xmi:ids so when I restore application state from workbench.xmi two different menu items launches the same command